# What's the most robust way to list installed software in debian based distros?

Tags: shell-script, debian, package-management, dpkg

So, for now, let's say we only need this to work for debian-based systems (but I will need to be able to do it for `yum` in the future).

The best I have right now is `dpkg-query`. So, for example, if I run this:

```
dpkg-query --show
```

I'll get a list like this (with a few thousand entries):

```
...  
sudo    1.8.17p1-2  
...  
vim     2:7.4.1829-1  
...
```

There is no naming convention though. Some of the packages have the version number in them, some of them have the architecture. ex `gcc-4.9-base:amd64`, but what I want would only have `gcc 4.9`. Ideally, I would like to be able to get vendor, product, and version information for all of the software installed. Is there any way to do this **natively**, or does it have to be some kind of "fuzzy" match?

I'm open to alternative ways of querying the package manager, or some other method that I am not thinking of. I am not able to install additional packages to accomplish this goal (though, I would be interested to see how they work if that exists).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will list the source packages and versions corresponding to the installed binary packages:

```
dpkg-query --show -f '${source:Package} ${source:Version}\n' | sort -u
```

This is the closest match to individual pieces of software you can get automatically: you'll only see `gcc-4.9` once, with the associated version, instead of all the corresponding binary packages. You can't easily retrieve "vendor" information, you'd need to look at the package details (`apt-cache show ...`) or the licensing information (in `/usr/share/doc/<package>/copyright` — it should point to the "upstream" project, *i.e.* the "vendor"); this isn't guaranteed to be in machine-readable format so there will be some human parsing involved.

You'll still find some source packages whose name contains the (major) version, *e.g.* `gcc-4.9`, `gcc-5` etc.; these are unavoidable when packages are designed so that major versions are co-installable, as is the case for GCC.

The equivalent RPM command is

```
rpm --qf "%{SOURCERPM}\n" -qa | sort -u
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reasoning for the (lack of) naming convention. I suppose that makes sense. The apt-cache could help some of the time, but definitely does not look like something I'd be able to automate  as you mentioned (unfortunately). Unless there is a totally new idea somewhere, it looks like dpkg will be the way to go. I can strip out the architecture consistently, but I am getting burned by the extraneous packages that seem to follow the convention product-{lib} or product-{version}, and unfortunately there are many products with a `-` in their name, so I can't just strip it out

Comment: If you use the `dpkg-query` command in my answer, you won't need to remove the architecture, and you'll see far fewer extraneous package names. There's no magic fix for the remaining issues though AFAICS.

Comment: Oh, awesome. I didn't see that part. Even better. Thanks again.

Comment: It may be better to include the `yum` version of the command VS `rpm`: `yum list installed`. I've always found `yum list` to be very consistent in it's output, always `[package]   [version]    [repository]`

Comment: @Centimane the `rpm` command I gave lists the source packages in a very consistent format; `yum list installed` lists binary packages, so you can get multiple hits for a single piece of upstream software.

Comment: @StephenKitt the rpm command seems like it would work. I get output that generally looks like this: `bash-4.2.46-20.el7_2.src.rpm`. So, to get the actual product name, I have to find the first `.`, then basically step back till I hit a `-` and then use everything before that. `yum list` also seems like it is querying repos as it checks mirror speeds before listing packages, but the output is a bit cleaner. nvm, more formatting options here: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Docs/QueryFormat

Comment: @Gray `rqm --querytags` will give you all the tags you can use in `--qf`. The main issue I was trying to address in both cases was to ensure that source packages are listed rather than binary packages, which produces a list tracking software more closely. The result is harder to parse in the RPM case, but needs less filtering than `yum list`'s output.

Answer (score 2):

On debian you can run `dpkg --list`

To get more information about a specific package run:

```
dpkg -p <package_name>
```

or

```
dpkg -s <package_name>
```

eg:

```
# dpkg -s gcc 
Package: gcc
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 42
Maintainer: Debian GCC Maintainers <debian-gcc@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: gcc-defaults (1.136)
Version: 4:4.9.2-2
Provides: c-compiler
Depends: cpp (>= 4:4.9.2-2), gcc-4.9 (>= 4.9.2-1~)
Recommends: libc6-dev | libc-dev
Suggests: gcc-multilib, make, manpages-dev, autoconf, automake, libtool,  flex, bison, gdb, gcc-doc
Conflicts: gcc-doc (<< 1:2.95.3)
Description: GNU C compiler
This is the GNU C compiler, a fairly portable optimizing compiler for C.
This is a dependency package providing the default GNU C compiler.
```

On RHEL based distro you can run `rpm -qa`

Comment: Does dpkg -s/-p source from the same data as apt-cache? Neither of them actually make queries to the repo, right? (I don't want them doing that).

Comment: It's not the same source of info directly, but ultimately it's the same (`apt-cache` will be up-to-date as of the last `apt-get update`, `dpkg` as of the last `dpkg --update-avail`; for installed packages the information should be accurate in both cases). Both commands only use local information, they don't access the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian, perhaps, you could use the option **--showformat=format** for *dpkg-query*.

As an exemple :

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${binary:Package}\t${Version}\t${Architecture}\t${binary:Summary}\n' gcc
```