# Is there a way to find patches which need testing from packages you have?

Tags: debian, package-management, search, bugs, bts-search

```
$ dpkg -l
```

Gives you a list of all packages installed on your system. Now some bugs on the Debian BTS are tagged **patch** . Now is there a way to list all packages which are installed on your system for which patches are out there in the Debian BTS. Building, test and reporting as in feedback would make the packages better and in turn Debian better. Is there a way to do it ?

Update - Bonus points if this can be done with a help of a CLI tool and not writing a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short script:

```
for source in $(dpkg-query --show -f '${source:Package}\n' | sort -u); do bts select source:${source} tag:patch; done
```

This uses `dpkg-query` to [list the installed source packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321908/86440), and `bts` (from the [`devscripts` package](https://tracker.debian.org/devscripts)) to list all bug numbers corresponding to an open bug with a patch filed against any of the source packages. It relies on packages' naming constraints to simplify parsing (there's no need to handle spaces or special characters).

I don't know of any existing command-line tool which does this.